# I want to enhance the memory performance of this game by storing only locations where velocity changes

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pygame

Please be gentle. I'm a pygame n00b and haven't touched pygame in years. This is my unique implementation of the classic game snake. In this game, the snake has a velocity which can vary along both axes of motion in increments of one pixel per frame and the tail follows the exact path the head travels as the snake moves about the screen. If you move too slowly, you die (an unintended behavior but I have deemed it desirable.) If you collide with your own tail, you die. If you collide with an edge, you die and if you reverse direction, you die. My question concerns the manner in which the snakes body is represented internally.

My original plan for implementing this game was to store only the points at which the head changed velocity. Behavior equivalent to the above game description would be implemented by computing a point between the first point beyond the length of the tail (always at index 0 of `SnakeTail.body`) and the next point and storing it as `SnakeTail.pos`. This would be the distance remaining after the distance between all other points and the head position were subtracted from index 1 in `SnakeTail.body`.

By doing all rendering and collision detection using `SnakeTail.pos`->`SnakeTail.body[1:]`->`head`, behavior equivalent to the above description and the below implementation could be achieved.

I was honestly surprised how complex this really was. Vector math is hard! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have researched this matter extensively and found no answers.

O_G_Python.py:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import pygame.math as vectmath
import pygame.font as font
import random

# Screen dimension constants
S_WIDTH                = 800
S_HEIGHT               = 600
SCREEN_DIMENSIONS      = (S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT)

# Numerical game constants.
UNIT_SIZE              = 15
NUM_SNACKS             = 5
SNAKE_MAX_SPEED        = 15
EVT_TIME               = pygame.USEREVENT
VELOCITY_INCREMENT     = 0.25
# Index constants
X                      = 0
Y                      = 1

# Vector constants.
INITIAL_VELOCITY       = vectmath.Vector2((2, 2))
INITIAL_POSITION       = vectmath.Vector2((S_WIDTH / 2, S_HEIGHT / 2))

# Color constants
PURPLE                 = (0x4b, 0x12, 0x54)
RED                    = (0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)
ORANGE                 = (0xf9, 0x7e, 0x20)
DARK_BLUE              = (0x0f, 0x13, 0x54)
WHITE                  = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)

# Some functions that will be used frequently within this game.
def lineEndpointOnReverseVector(vect, startPos, lineLen, unitSize = 1):
    lineLen *= unitSize
    # Invert the vector
    vect = vectmath.Vector2( -vect.x, -vect.y )
    # Normalize the vector.
    vect = vect.normalize()
    # Scale the normalized vector by the desired length.
    vect.x *= lineLen; vect.y *= lineLen
    # Offset the vector by startPos and return it.
    return vectmath.Vector2(startPos.x + vect.x, startPos.y + vect.y)

class LinkedVector:
    def __init__ (self, position, parent):
        # Copying both of these may be sub optimal in terms of memory usage, but
        # it makes this class more reusable.
        self.pos = vectmath.Vector2((position.x, position.y))
        self.parent = vectmath.Vector2((parent.x, parent.y))

        self.dist = self.pos.distance_to(self.parent)

# The snake head gets its own class because I want it to be responsible for
# rendering itself.
class SnakeHead:
    def __init__ (self, initHeadPos, initHeadVel):
        self.pos = vectmath.Vector2(initHeadPos)
        self.vel = vectmath.Vector2(initHeadVel)
        self.prevVel = None
        self.color = ORANGE

# The way the tail gets rendered has complex dependencies on the number of
# bends in the snake and its length so this gets its own class too.
class SnakeTail:
    def __init__ (self, initPos, initLen, initBody = None):
        self.pos = initPos
        if initBody == None:
            self.body = [LinkedVector(
                              vectmath.Vector2((0, 0)),
                              initPos
                            )]
        else:
            self.body = initBody

        self.bodyLen = initLen
        self.color = DARK_BLUE

    def update (self, head):

        # Get rid of all bends in the snake body which are beyond the total length of
        # the snake except the first as this is used for linear interpolation in the draw
        # method.
        headToFirstBendDist = head.pos.distance_to(self.body[-1].pos)

        if headToFirstBendDist > self.bodyLen:
            # In case of the whole body being out of the range of the first bend,
            # calculate the coordinates of the end point of a line on a linear interpolation
            # between the head and the last point in the body list which contains all the bends
            # in the snake.
            self.pos = head.pos.lerp(self.body[-1].pos, (float(self.bodyLen) / float(headToFirstBendDist)) % 1.0)
            self.body = [LinkedVector(self.pos, head.pos)]
            return # That's all our work done in this case.

        # Iterate over the points and discard the points out of bounds of the snakes body length.
        distanceSoFar = headToFirstBendDist
        newBody = [self.body[-1]]
        clearedFirstElement = False
        for idx in range(-1, -len(self.body) - 1, -1):
            point = self.body[idx]

            # Keep the points that are within range of the head given the current body length.
            if self.bodyLen > distanceSoFar + point.dist:
                if not clearedFirstElement:
                    newBody.insert(0, point)
                else:
                    newBody[0] = point
                distanceSoFar += point.dist


            else:

                # TODO: Add calcs to compute a point between the current point and self.body[1] at distance
                # distanceSoFar - self.bodyLen to make it possible to store only the points at which velocity
                # changes and still produce the same behavior.

                self.body = newBody
                return


    def draw (self, screen, head):
        for idx, point in enumerate(self.body):

            # Drawing code to be used if the above TODO is successfully implemented.
            # if idx == 0:
                # pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)), int(UNIT_SIZE / 2))
                # if len(self.body) >= 2:
                    # pygame.draw.line(
                                      # screen,
                                      # self.color,
                                      # (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)),
                                      # (int(self.body[idx + 1].pos.x), int(self.body[idx + 1].pos.y)),
                                      # UNIT_SIZE
                                    # )
                # else:
                    # pygame.draw.line(
                                      # screen,
                                      # self.color,
                                      # (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)),
                                      # (int(head.pos.x), int(head.pos.y)),
                                      # UNIT_SIZE
                                    # )

            if idx in range(0, len(self.body) - 2):
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(point.pos.x), int(point.pos.y)), int(UNIT_SIZE / 2))
                pygame.draw.line(
                                  screen,
                                  self.color,
                                  (int(point.pos.x), int(point.pos.y)),
                                  (int(self.body[idx + 1].pos.x), int(self.body[idx + 1].pos.y)),
                                  UNIT_SIZE
                                )
            else:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(point.pos.x), int(point.pos.y)), int(UNIT_SIZE / 2))
                pygame.draw.line(
                                  screen,
                                  self.color,
                                  (int(point.pos.x), int(point.pos.y)),
                                  (int(head.pos.x), int(head.pos.y)),
                                  UNIT_SIZE
                                )

class Snake:
    def __init__ (self, initHeadPos, initHeadVel, initLen = 5 * UNIT_SIZE):
        self.head = SnakeHead(initHeadPos, initHeadVel)
        tailPos = lineEndpointOnReverseVector(
                              self.head.vel,
                              self.head.pos,
                              initLen,
                              UNIT_SIZE
                            )
        self.tail = SnakeTail(
                               tailPos,
                               initLen,
                               [LinkedVector(tailPos, self.head.pos)]
                             )

    def addToVel (self, velocity, limit = -1):
        # Store a copy of the current velocity for collision detection and rendering purposes.
        self.head.prevVel = vectmath.Vector2((self.head.vel.x, self.head.vel.y))

        if limit >= 0:
            # Handle cases of the speed being limited by adding the velocity
            # and checking to see if it's over the limit.
            alteredVel = vectmath.Vector2((
                          self.head.vel.x + velocity[X],
                          self.head.vel.y + velocity[Y]
                        ))

            if alteredVel.magnitude() <= limit:
                self.head.vel = alteredVel
                reachedLimit = False
            else:

                reachedLimit = True

        else:
            self.head.vel = vectmath.Vector2((
                          self.head.vel.x + velocity[X],
                          self.head.vel.y + velocity[Y]
                        ))
            reachedLimit = False

        # Set the prevVel property to None if velocity is not 0 to tell the update and draw methods to
        # use the current velocity.
        if self.head.vel.x != 0 or self.head.vel.y != 0:
            self.head.prevVel = None

        if reachedLimit:
            self.head.color = DARK_BLUE
            self.tail.color = ORANGE
        else:
            self.head.color = ORANGE
            self.tail.color = DARK_BLUE
            # Append the coordinates at which the head changed direction to the bends list.
            self.tail.body.append(LinkedVector(self.head.pos, self.tail.body[-1].pos))
        # Return reachedLimit. This will be used by the game loop to briefly change how the snake is
        # rendered if the user tries to go over the speed limit.
        return reachedLimit

    def createHeadTriangle (self, velocity, position):
        # Transform the verticies of the isociles triangle below to make
        # it face the direction of motion and translate to the heads
        # position on the screen.
        headLen = UNIT_SIZE * 2
        headWidth = UNIT_SIZE * 1

        # The coords of the three verticies positioned around the origin to make the
        # rotation easier.
        topLeft = vectmath.Vector2(-float(headWidth / 2), -float(headLen / 2))
        topRight = vectmath.Vector2(float(headWidth / 2), -float(headLen / 2))
        bottomCenter = vectmath.Vector2(0.0, float(headLen / 2))

        theta = vectmath.Vector2(velocity).angle_to(vectmath.Vector2(0, 1))

        topLeft = topLeft.rotate(-theta)
        topRight = topRight.rotate(-theta)
        bottomCenter = bottomCenter.rotate(-theta)

        # For now, just return this triangle to see how it looks.
        return (
                 (int(topRight.x) + position[X], int(topRight.y) + position[Y]),
                 (int(topLeft.x) + position[X], int(topLeft.y) + position[Y]),
                 (int(bottomCenter.x) + position[X], int(bottomCenter.y) + position[Y])
               )

    def getHeadTriangle (self):
        # This getter gets the head triangle facing the direction of motion when velocity is
        # non-zero and returns the head facing along the previous velocity vector in cases of
        # the head velocity being 0 to stop the head snapping to theta = 0.
        if self.head.prevVel != None:
            return self.createHeadTriangle(self.head.prevVel, self.head.pos)
        else:
            return self.createHeadTriangle(self.head.vel, self.head.pos)

    def collidedWithTail (self):

        headTriangle = self.getHeadTriangle()
        for idx in range(0, len(self.tail.body) - 45):
            point = self.tail.body[idx]

            x, y = (point.pos.x, point.pos.y)
            for vertex in headTriangle:
                a = x - vertex[X] - x if vertex[X] > x else vertex[X] - x
                b = y - vertex[Y] - y if vertex[Y] > y else vertex[Y] - y
                if a*a + b*b <= (UNIT_SIZE / 2) * (UNIT_SIZE / 2): return True

                # TODO: Add additional check to see if the points in the head come within UNIT_SIZE / 2
                # of the line segment from tail.body[idx] to tail.body[idx + 1] and the line segment
                # tail.pos to tail.body[0] to accomodate the TODO optimization described above.

    def update (self, screenW, screenH):

        self.head.pos.x += self.head.vel.x
        self.head.pos.y += self.head.vel.y

        headTriangle = self.getHeadTriangle()

        # Append a new point to the snake body.
        self.tail.body.append(LinkedVector(self.head.pos, self.tail.body[-1].pos))

        # Update the tail.
        self.tail.update(self.head)

        # Detect edge collisions and return True if the collision has occurred.
        for point in headTriangle:
            if point[X] < 0 or point[X] > S_WIDTH:
                return True
            if point[Y] < 0 or point[Y] > S_HEIGHT:
                return True

        return self.collidedWithTail()

    def draw (self, screen):
        if self.head.prevVel != None:
            # Get the head triangle at the previous velocity to keep it from snapping to theta = 0.
            headTriangle = self.createHeadTriangle(self.head.prevVel, self.head.pos)

        else:
            # The current velocity is not 0.
            headTriangle = self.createHeadTriangle(self.head.vel, self.head.pos)

        self.tail.draw(screen, self.head)
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.head.color, headTriangle)

def main ():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_DIMENSIONS)
    pygame.display.set_caption("0 G Python")

    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    snake = Snake(INITIAL_POSITION, INITIAL_VELOCITY)

    snackCoords = [
                  vectmath.Vector2((random.randint(8, S_WIDTH - 8), random.randint(8, S_HEIGHT - 8)))

                  for x in range(NUM_SNACKS)
                ]

    score = 0
    gameFontName = "freesansbold.ttf"
    gameFontName = font.match_font(gameFontName)
    # Cross-platform compatibility stuff.
    if gameFontName == None:
        gameFontName = font.match_font(font.get_default_font())
        gameFont = font.Font(gameFontName, 30)
    else:
        gameFont = font.Font(gameFontName, 30)

    time = 0
    pygame.time.set_timer(EVT_TIME, 1000)

    # Key held boolean flags
    upHeld = False
    downHeld = False
    leftHeld = False
    rightHeld = False

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    upHeld = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    downHeld = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    leftHeld = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    rightHeld = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    upHeld = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    downHeld = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    leftHeld = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    rightHeld = False

            if event.type == EVT_TIME:
                time += 1

        # Update the snakes velocity.
        if upHeld:
            snake.addToVel((0, -VELOCITY_INCREMENT), SNAKE_MAX_SPEED)

        if downHeld:
            snake.addToVel((0,  VELOCITY_INCREMENT), SNAKE_MAX_SPEED)

        if leftHeld:
            snake.addToVel((-VELOCITY_INCREMENT, 0), SNAKE_MAX_SPEED)

        if rightHeld:
            snake.addToVel((VELOCITY_INCREMENT,  0), SNAKE_MAX_SPEED)

        # Update the snake.
        collisionDetected = snake.update(S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT)

        if collisionDetected:
            score = 0
            time = 0
            snake = Snake(INITIAL_POSITION, INITIAL_VELOCITY)
            snackCoords = [
                  vectmath.Vector2((random.randint(8, S_WIDTH - 8), random.randint(8, S_HEIGHT - 8)))

                  for x in range(NUM_SNACKS)
                ]

        # Fill in the background.
        screen.fill(PURPLE)

        # Draw the score onto the screen.
        scoreSurface = gameFont.render(f"Score: {score}", False, WHITE)
        screen.blit(scoreSurface, (5, 5))
        timeSurface = gameFont.render(f"Time: {time}", False, WHITE)
        screen.blit(timeSurface, (5, scoreSurface.get_height() + 5))

        # Render the snacks onto the screen and generate new coordinates for snacks
        # if all the snacks have been eaten.
        if len(snackCoords) != 0:
            tempSnacks = []
            headTriangle = snake.getHeadTriangle()
            for idx, snack in enumerate(snackCoords):
                beenEaten = False
                intSnack = ( int(snack.x), int(snack.y) )
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, intSnack, int(UNIT_SIZE / 2))

                # Check for collisions between the snakes head and a snack.
                for point in headTriangle:
                    a = point[X] - snack.x if point[X] > snack.x else snack.x - point[X]
                    b = point[Y] - snack.y if point[Y] > snack.y else snack.y - point[Y]
                    if a * a + b * b < (UNIT_SIZE / 2) * (UNIT_SIZE / 2):
                        beenEaten = True
                        snake.tail.bodyLen += UNIT_SIZE * 5
                        score += 5

                if not beenEaten: tempSnacks.append(snack)

            snackCoords = tempSnacks

        else:
            snackCoords = [
                  vectmath.Vector2((random.randint(8, S_WIDTH - 8), random.randint(8, S_HEIGHT - 8)))

                  for x in range(NUM_SNACKS)
                ]

        # Render the snake onto the screen.
        snake.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: I dramatically improved the gameplay by changing acceleration from key pressed to key held.

Edit: improved phrasing to make the question more understandable.